# C++, boost asio, receive null terminated string

Tags: c++, string, sockets, boost, boost-asio

How can I retrieve null-terminated string from a socket using the boost::asio library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
m_socket = boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service);
boost::asio::streambuf replyBuf;
...
...
boost::asio::read_until(m_socket, replyBuf, '\0');
```

And if you want to transform the streambuf to a string:

```
std::string retVal((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&replyBuf)),
                        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```